# Receiving only bytecode of images using jQuery .load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, dom

I am receiving the bytecode of loaded images by using jQuery [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

Is it

1. because there's no MIMEType specified?
2. because I am using an image url without file extension?
3. because I have to wrap the whole thing somehow?

Here is some examplary code:

**HTML**

```
  <div class="slide" data-img-src="http://lorempixel.com/200/100/technics/">
    <div class="slide-content">
      <h1>Heading 1</h1>
      <p>Just some random text for demonstration purposes.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="slide" data-img-src="http://lorempixel.com/200/100/nature/">
    <div class="slide-content">
      <h1>Heading 1</h1>
      <p>Just some random text for demonstration purposes.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**Javascript**

```
var ajax_load = "<img src='img/load.gif' alt='loading...' />";

$(".slide").each(function(index, el) {
    var img_src = $(this).attr('data-img-src');

    $(this).prepend(ajax_load);
    $(this).load(img_src, null, function() {
        console.log(img_src + " loaded");
    });
});
```

And a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/BCLJE/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what I'd expect to happen if you tried to set the contents of an image (loaded via AJAX, no less) into a field that just accepts text. If you want to replace the contents of those elements with the images themselves, create `<img>` elements that have the correct `src` attribute:

```
var $img = $('<img/>', {src: img_src}).load(function(e) {
    // do something when the image has actually loaded?
});
$(this).empty().append($img);
```

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BCLJE/8/)

Comment: why do you use a dollarsign before your variable name?
and could you please explain $('<img/>', {src: img_src}) to me?

Comment: @Manticore The dollar sign at the start of the variable name is a popular convention to indicate that the variable references a jQuery object, so you know that you can call jQuery methods on it. It's by no means required.

Comment: The `$('</img>', {src: img_src})` part is the variation of the (heavily) overloaded jQuery function used to create new DOM elements. In this case I'm creating a new `<img>` element (represented by the first argument: `'<img/>'`), and the second argument is an object that has the properties to set for that element (in this case, it's just setting the `src` property to the value of `new_src`).

Answer (score 2):

you need to make sure the data or HTML fragments you are trying to retrieve are on the same domain. Due to **same origin policy**

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

> Due to browser security restrictions, most "Ajax" requests are subject to the same origin policy; the request can not successfully retrieve data from a different domain, subdomain, or protocol.

its under **additional notes** for the **load()** API shorthand method:

http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: if the images and web page is not on the same server than you will not be able to pull in data to a different domain on a different server due to security restrictions .. you could try a different AJAX method maybe using JSONP .. here is an article about using JSONP and AJAX for cross domain data retrieval - http://www.webdevdoor.com/jquery/cross-domain-browser-json-ajax/ -